# postgres change data type of view column from unknown to text

Tags: postgresql, view, sqldatatypes

I just create a new view as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW gettreelistvw AS 
 SELECT "CRM".groupid, 'pointrewarding'::text AS applicationid, "CM".menuid, "CM".menuname, "CM".levelstructure, "CM".moduleid, "CM".haschild, "CM".installed
   FROM core_capabilitymap "CRM"
   JOIN core_menus "CM" ON "CRM".menuid::text = "CM".menuid::text;

ALTER TABLE gettreelistvw
```

when i execute this error appear

> ERROR:  cannot change data type of view column "applicationid" from
>   unknown to text

although I already cast the value of applicationid column to text. it's still recognized as unkown datatype

```
'pointrewarding'::text
```

The alternative method of postgres conversion also didn't work.

```
CAST('pointrewarding' AS TEXT)
```

How to solve this problem.

Comment: You should check this on the StackExchange DBA :
http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/586/cant-rename-columns-in-postgresql-views-with-create-or-replace

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to change the data type of a view's columns, you have to drop it, then create it.

[Version 9.2 docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createview.html)

> CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW .... The new query must generate the same columns that were generated by the existing view query (that is, the **same column names** in the **same order** and with the **same data types**), but it may add additional columns to the end of the list.

Emphasis added.

Comment: This is still correct as of Version 15.